# Fill a DataGridView according to the selected row of the parent's one

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 DataGridView controls, I have to fill the second one according to the idGarantie of the selected row of my first dataGridView

***Here is the First DGV where I show the Garanties***

```
        var queryGaranties = from g in serviceGaranties.Liste()
            join t in serviceTauxCotisation.Liste() on g.idGarantie equals t.idGarantie
            select new {g.idGarantie, g.libelGarantie, t.tauxA, t.tauxB};

        GridGaranties.DataSource = queryGaranties.ToList();
        GridGaranties.DataBind();
```

***Here is the second one :***

```
    protected void GridGaranties_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var queryClauses = from c in serviceClauses.Liste()
            join g in serviceGaranties.Liste() on c.idGarantie equals g.idGarantie
            join n in serviceNiveauGaranties.Liste() on c.idClause equals n.idClause
            where c.idGarantie == **// find idGarantie on selected row of GridGaranties**
            select new {c.idClause, c.libelClause, n.TauxCouvA, n.TauxCouvB};

        GridClauses.DataSource = queryClauses.ToList();
        GridClauses.DataBind();
    }
```

can I use the DataKeyNames with or should I take the value of the cell in the selected row ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, store relevant values of GridGaranties in RowDataBound

```
protected void GridGaranties_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
       e.Row.Attributes.Add("idGarantie", (int)rowView["idGarantie"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Then read back your attribute in SelectedIndexChanged

```
protected void GridGaranties_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var selectedRow = GridGaranties.SelectedRow;
   int idGarantie = Int32.Parse(selectedRow.Attributes["idGarantie"]);

   //Now you can perform your query
}
```

Hope that it helps